# Secrets storage in Python

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm new to flask programming, I see that flask has secret keys config and database URI config. I'm wondering if it is a good idea to create a Secrets class, in a new file called secret.py, to store secret keys and such (This file will be in git ignore obviously)

```py
class Secrets:
    def __init__(self):
        self.secret_key = "secret_key"
        self.database_path = "secret_path"
```

and in my app.py file i will import it like this

```py
from secret import Secret
secret = Secret()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = secret.database_path
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secret.secret_key
```

Is what i propose a good idea or is it dumb,if its dumb pls tell me why.

Comment: No. Good practice is to use .env file and read database credentials from it. And add the .env file to gitignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above, there is no need to instantiate `Secret`, as you just access the class variables.

Also, usually you create a `Config` class for Flask.

The only sub-optimal thing about your code would be that you hardcode secrets in your code - this means, that when you push your code e.g. to GitHub others can see your credentials.

Thatswhy usually environment variables are used to provide secrets for production.

Have a look at Miguel Grinberg's great tutorial, especially this chapter:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure